# How to show and hide a table column after checking a condition in every row in ng repeat loop angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, show-hide

I have a problem with show/hide column in a table with `ng-repeat` after checking a condition. Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-no-pad-mob">
        <div class="content-box-with-label without-label with-data-view">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-data-view">
                <tr>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th>Fee Type</th>
                    <th>Fee</th>
                    <th class="th_DSCR_Cal">Capitalize</th>
                    <th class="th_DSCR_Cal">Amortize</th>
                    <th>Amortized Interest</th>
                    <th>Recurring Fee</th>
                    <th class="boo-tbl-tr-config">Setting</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="amo in item.trialCalculation.listTrialAmortization | filter:{active: true}">
                    <td class="boo-tbl-tr-config">
                        <md-checkbox ng-model="amo.isApply" ng-change="GenerateFee_ChangeEvent(item.trialCalculation.listTrialAmortization,amo, item)" aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-value="amo.isApply" ng-disabled="statusMatched == true"></md-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{amo.feeType}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" step=".01" ng-model="amo.fee" ng-readonly="statusMatched == true || amo.feeType ==='Stamp Duty'|| amo.feeType ==='Document Fee'|| amo.feeType ==='Introducer Fee'|| amo.feeType ==='Insurance Fee'" ng-disabled="amo.isApply === false"
                               ng-pattern="/[0-9.,]+/" format="number" type="text" ng-change="ResetAmortization_ChangeEvent(item.trialCalculation.listTrialAmortization,amo, item)">
                    </td>
                    <td class="boo-tbl-tr-config">
                        <md-checkbox ng-model="amo.capitalize" ng-change="ValidateCapitalize_ChangeEvent(item.trialCalculation.listTrialAmortization,amo)" aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-disabled="statusMatched == true ||  amo.isApply == false || amo.isCapitalizeEnable == false || amo.amortize == true"></md-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="boo-tbl-tr-config">
                        <md-checkbox ng-model="amo.amortize" ng-change="GenerateAmortization_ChangeEvent(item.trialCalculation.listTrialAmortization,amo, item)" aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-value="amo.amortize" ng-disabled="statusMatched == true ||  amo.isApply == false || amo.isAmortizeEnable == false || amo.capitalize == true"></md-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" step=".01" ng-model="amo.amortizedInterest" ng-disabled
                               ng-pattern="/[0-9.,]+/" format="number" type="text" ng-readonly="true">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" step=".01" ng-model="amo.recurringFee" ng-disabled
                               ng-pattern="/[0-9.,]+/" format="number" type="text" ng-readonly="true">
                    </td>
                    <td ng-hide="statusMatched == true" class="boo-tbl-tr-config">
                        <a href="#" ng-show="cprinit.editable==true && (amo.isCapitalizeEnable==false || amo.amortize==true)"
                           ng-click="GenerateAmortization_ChangeEvent(item.trialCalculation.listTrialAmortization,amo, item)" ng-disabled="amo.isApply === false || amo.amortize === false"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="statusMatched == true" class="add_new_expen">
                    <td colspan="8">
                        <md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary inline-input" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addincomemodal_{{$index}}">
                            <md-icon md-svg-src="~/Content/images/add-plus-button.svg"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                        <label class="label-addnewexpen" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addincomemodal_{{$index}}">Add New Fee Type</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to show settings column if only if all the data rows should be checked a condition and at least one row is passed the condition. If any of data row is not able to pass the condition the settings column should not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function in your controller to this. Loop through all the rows to check for the condition, set  `$scope.shColumn = true` when the condition is met.

In your HTML.

```
<th ng-if="shColumn">Settings</th>
```